# Open the same php website twice

Tags: php, file, asynchronous, download

I don't understand why you mark this as a duplicate, there is no correlation between the other problem and mine...
To clarify: I dont open up different connections to multiple websites, it's only one domain "example.org/index.php or example.org/download.php"
Also there is written you can have 6 simoultaneous connections with chrome, for me even opening download.php two time doesn't work, so that can't be the same problem.

I have a website index.php where you put a link into an inputbox and then you can click a download button. This starts the download.php site which analyzes the link and downloads the file.

My problem is: if i open the index.php in two different tabs and start two downloads then, the second download starts only after the first download is over. It seems like download.php is locked while its being executed by another tab.

For example if i open `example.org/youtube-dl/download.php?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%abcabcabc&format=mp4`
to download a youtube video, the webserver starts processing. But when I want to download another video, lets say defdefdef I open `example.org/youtube-dl/download.php?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%defdefdef&format=mp3`
the webserver dont starts the process. Chrome is loading and when the first download is finished, then download.php is getting executed and the second download starts.

Is it possible to let the download.php executed multiple times in parallel?

Comment: [curl_multi_*](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: sorry that is not helping, because i dont use curl and never said i do.

Comment: Solution: `session_write_close();` - because I used `session_start();` in the php file the second tab could load the download.php only if the first php site was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
session_write_close();
```

because I used `session_start();` in the php file, the second tab could load the download.php, only if the first php site was closed.